# How to calculate binomial coefficient C(n, r) modulo some prime power?

Tags: combinatorics

How to calculate C(n, r) modulo m, m is of the form p^a, where p is prime.

Here C(n, r) means n choose r. The range of n and r is large (of the order of 10^18) so it cannot be solved by calculating the power of primes. Also m is less than 10^6. I tried reading the generalization of Lucas Theorem, but could not understand it. It will be really helpful if someone could explain a feasible method to solve the problem.

Till now I have tried this. I stored every prime number from 1 to n in an array p[]. Then calculated the power of pi  1<=i<=|p| in n! and added it to arr[i]. Similarly calculated the power of pi 1 <=i<=|p| from 1 to r in r! and subtracted it from arr[i]. Same for (n-r)!. Then multiplied (p[i]^arr[i])%(p^a) to answer while taking modulo. But this runs in O(n) which is too slow for the above mentioned constraints.

There is a citation in the wikipedia page of [Lucas's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem#cite_note-3) for generalized form of Lucas's theorem but the link is not working.

Comment: [Hint: Software Engineering Stack Exchange... expect research before asking](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7826/31260)

Comment: @gnat I apologize. I am new to the community. I will add everything that I have tried till now.

Answer (score 0):

If this is you trying to solve a problem in a programming competition, don't read any further, because using outside help is *cheating*.

Very simple. You are calculating a product of numbers x(i) modulo m. These numbers x (i) are consecutive integers. If there are n or more of them, then one must be equal to 0 (modulo m). And in that case, the whole product is 0 (modulo m). Actually, if there are a*p or more, then you have a numbers divisible by p, so the product is divisible by m = p^a, so the product is 0.

Therefore, all the cases where the product is not 0 modulo m can be solved with fewer than m multiplications.

Comment: Yes. But what if the numerator and denominator have the same power of p. In this case they cancel out and the result is not zero. eg. C(50, 10) modulo (25) = 20, C(6, 2) modulo (2) = 1.

Comment: Don't think of C(n,r) in terms of a fraction. The denominator *always* entirely cancels with part of the numerator. The easiest way of thinking of it is as specifying part of the sequence of products that is omitted.